# How to upload an image to Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am doing a project and new to react. I go through some tutorials and learn about react and firebase. Now i done with adding and reading text from firebase. i am sending modal to my react firebase to show data like name, estate and description.

now i have to render images to, for that i explore the documentation and facing some issue what I want to do is to convert the image to url and store it in my data in firebase but unable to do that facing issue like
childPath.split is not a function

```
TypeError: childPath.split is not a function
    at child (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24099:40)
    at _getChild$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25823:19)
    at refFromPath (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25872:14)
    at refFromPath (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25865:14)
    at ref$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25886:12)
    at ref (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26249:10)
    at uploadFiles (http://localhost:3000/main.a1c7807c27fe7005bb39.hot-update.js:52:79)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.a1c7807c27fe7005bb39.hot-update.js:75:13
    at commitHookEffectListMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55328:30)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:56821:17)
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db, storage } from "../../Firebase-Config";
import { collection, getDocs, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

import "../../../src/App.css";

const ShowPost = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [estate, setEstate] = useState("");

  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
  const userCollectionRef = collection(db, "posts");

  const handleButton = async () => {
    await addDoc(userCollectionRef, {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      estate: estate,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const uploadFiles = () => {
      const fileName = new Date().getTime() + file.name;
      console.log(fileName);
      const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fileName);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running");
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
          });
        }
      );
    };
    file && uploadFiles();
  }, [file]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(userCollectionRef);
      setUser(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      // console.log(data);
    };
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
        placeholder="estate"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setDescription(e.target.value);
        }}
        placeholder="description"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEstate(e.target.value);
        }}
        placeholder="name"
      />
      <button onClick={handleButton}>Click me</button>

      <div className="square center-div">
        {user.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="circle-pfp">{item.description}</div>
              <h3>{item.estate}</h3>
              <h1>{item.name}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowPost;
```

code - https://github.com/mohitRana-04/real-estate/tree/post

my motive is to store the url in a useState then i'll upload the state in my modal so that i can call the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the `file` is truth in `useEffect` is great as we don't have file data in the very beginning. However, the initial value of `file` is set to an empty array`[]`, which is `true` in the condition.

I believe that's the reason the error happened. Now the `[].name` is `undefined` and `fileName` is `NaN`. ( `number` + `undefined` = `NaN`)

As `split` is a function of `string` and fileName brings a `NaN` to the `ref` function, which means it's calling something like this:

```
 NaN.split() // TypeError
```

As we expect the file should be a blob data and not exist in the very beginning, set `null` to it would fix this issue.

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(); // make it a really false in condition
```